# A witch, a vampire and a pixie meet in a bar and talk about tomatoes eradicating humanity

Tags: story-identification, novel, magic, powers

I remember reading a series of books that took place in the Unites States in our time, but some  50 years ago or so there was a problem with genetically modified tomatoes eradicating most of humanity - except the supernatural entities in our world decided that this is their time to shine and help the humans, so they revealed that all those fairy tales we know have always been true.

The story is about a witch who was working for an agency that was trying to fight criminal supernatural creatures. One day she has a job together with a female vampire and a male pixie who were also working for this agency. Somehow they rescue a creature that can help them with a little head-start for their own business and they decide to quit their job at the agency. They talk about this plan in a bar.

Which turns out not to be the greatest idea because this agency doesn't like people quitting.

There were multiple books in this series. What I described was the start of the first one. I've read all of them in German and the word "Blut" (meaning *blood*) was in the title of every book of the series.

Random stuff I remember from the series:

- humans had a deep fear for tomatoes
- supernaturals were immune to the disease of the tomatoes leaving tomatoes something of a delicacy for them
- there were a lot of different creatures throughout the series:

  - witches
  - werewolves
  - pixies
  - fairies
  - demons
  - ...
- the witch was obsessed with shoes - especially her boots
- after some time the three protagonists moved into a church
- there were some romantic scenes between the witch and the vampire in later books, though they never really got together

I can't remember the name of the series and I haven't finished the series. Can you help me identify what books I am remembering so that I may continue reading the series? I would prefer information about the first book. I think there were about 10 books and I have read maybe 6 or 7 of them, but I am not sure. I've read them a few years back and the newer ones were just getting printed in Germany.

Comment: I thought this question was a start to a joke

Comment: I'm still waiting for the punchline

Comment: @Edlothiad I want to read the other books to find out what the punchline is. And thanks for the edit.

Comment: That is the best reply I could imagine!

Comment: You better have a better punchline that Mia Wallace's tomato joke!

Comment: Sounded like a weird episode of Attack of the Killer Tomatoes

Comment: @user13267 The three are are trying to formulate a plan to stop the rampaging plants. The pixie suggests distracting them with salsa dancing and then picking them off one by one. "Perfect!" cries the witch. "We can mash, blend, and boil them. We might even add some basil and oregano." The vampire smiles and says, "That sounds like a soup herb plan!"

Comment: @Edlothiad - ... The vampire says to the bartender, "I'd like a pitcher of beer for me and my friends here.". The bartender looks at the pixie and the witch and replies, "I'm sorry, but we don't serve food here."

Answer (score 43, accepted):

## [The Hollows Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollows_(series)) by Kim Harrison

The Tomato-part checks out on this, as well as the titles.

Relevant part from the above wiki:

> The alternate history is built upon two premises: the recent open existence of magical and supernatural species, primarily witches, vampires, and werewolves, with the human population; and the historical investment of Cold War military spending in genetic engineering as opposed to the Space Race, which resulted in the accidental release of a genetically modified tomato in the 1960s that killed a significant portion of the human population. The series is set approximately forty years after this plague, referred to as 'The Turn' within the series.

There are 13 books in the series with 12 novellas.

The list of books in publication order are as follows (for the reading order, the author's official website has [more information](http://www.kimharrison.net/SecondaryPages/BookOrder.html):

1. Dead Witch Walking
2. The Good, The Bad, and The Undead
   2.1  Undead in the Garden of Good and Evil (Ivy novella in the Dates From Hell anthology, also in Into the Woods compilation)
3. Every Which Way But Dead
4. A Fistful of Charms
   4.1  Dirty Magic (Mia short story in the Hotter Than Hell anthology, also in Into the Woods compilation)
5. For A Few Demons More
   5.1  The Bridges of Eden Park (Kisten/Rachel short story in For a Few Demons More(US mass market edition), also in Into the Woods compilation)
   5.2  Two Ghosts For Sister Rachel (Robbie/Rachel/Pierce novella in the Holidays Are Hell anthology, also in Into the Woods compilation)
6. The Outlaw Demon Wails (retitled Where Demons Dare in the UK)
   6.1  The Bespelled (Ceri/Al short story in The Outlaw Demon Wails (US mass market edition), also in the Demons anthology and the Into the Woods compilation)
7. White Witch, Black Curse
   7.1  Ley Line Drifter (Bis/Jenks novella in Unbound anthology, also in Into the Woods compilation)
8. Black Magic Sanction
9. Pale Demon
   9.1  Blood Work (Graphic novel of Rachel's internship under Ivy at the Inderlander Security)
   9.2  The Hollows Insider (The Hollows world book - an overarching new story, character profiles, maps, spell guides, charm recipes, secret correspondence, ... )
10. A Perfect Blood
    10.1 Million-Dollar Baby (Trent novella an Into the Woods original)
    10.2 Blood Crime (Graphic Novel of Rachel's continued interning under Ivy at the IS)
    10.3 Trouble on Reserve
11. Ever After
12. The Undead Pool
13. The Witch With No Name
    13.1  Sudden Backtrack

Comment: I'm going to update your info with details from the English page for the novels

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot :).

Comment: Not a problem. It's rude of me to be stealing your answer just because I found more details, so I edited them in!

Comment: @Edlothiad, if only more people behaved like that... :-)

Comment: @user35594 There is another user that's very good at doing that. But most seem to be obsessed with other online points. But I'm sure they will learn from example :)

Comment: Should they be read in the order listed @Edlothiad ?

Comment: @Tim that is not what that says. That is simply a publication order. There exists a chronological order as well. Which they should be read in, I have no idea :) I've edited the answer to include the author's "reading order"

Comment: I read this series completely out of order... and heartily recommend you read it *in* order.  Too many spoilers.  (Still loved the series.)

Comment: Drat a question to which I knew the answer and missed out LOL.  This is a great series to read.

Comment: Further info (not on that Wikipedia site). She has a new prequel series going specifically covering the turn, and the first book: [The Turn: The Hollows Begins with Death](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/31140515-the-turn) has been out since February.

Comment: @Tim - The main books reading order is publication order. the short stories, etc. fit in various places, but don't need to be read for the main series to make sense.